# Trying to get XML response using cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm trying to do a POST action on a webservice, which should return an XML file. After that, I'm trying to display the XML file. My .php currently looks like this:

```
echo "Downloading XML" . "\n";

$xml = file_get_contents('xml.xml');
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://secure.microincasso.nl/PaymentCampaign/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: text/xml'
));

$sXML = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "sXML: " . "\n";
echo $sXML;
echo "\n" . "endof:sXML" . "\n";

echo "Parsing XML\n";
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
echo "\nXML parsed\n\n";
foreach ($oXML->entry as $oEntry)
{
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

As you can see, the `xml.xml` file is sent as a POST parameter. This XML file is correct. The output I get, is the following:

> Downloading XML sXML: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Content-Type: text/xml Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Fri, 25 Oct
>   2013 16:44:53 GMT f8ac1882-e219-47b7-8d5a-71f64ee04caf
>   https://payment.microincasso.nl/Payment/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   endof:sXML Parsing XML  Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct()
>   [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in D:\Users\xxxxxx\send.php on
>   line 46
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct()
>   [simplexmlelement.--construct]: HTTP/1.1 200 OK in
>   D:\Users\xxxxxx\send.php on line 46
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct()
>   [simplexmlelement.--construct]: ^ in
>   D:\Users\xxxxxx\send.php on line 46
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could
>   not be parsed as XML' in D:\Users\xxxxxx\send.php:46 Stack
>   trace: #0 D:\Users\xxxxxx\send.php(46):
>   SimpleXMLElement->__construct('HTTP/1.1 200 OK...') #1 {main} thrown
>   in D:\xxxxxx\send.php on line 46

So in short, the link I'm trying to get is in the response. The response contains the stuff I need. But, the response doesn't seem to be XML. If you navigate to https://secure.microincasso.nl/PaymentCampaign/ directly, you'll see XML. What am I doing wrong? Why don't I have XML in the php script but plain text? How am I getting raw XML?

Comment: I see an XML error message. Are you sure that the response is _always_ XML?

Comment: @zneak Do you run my code? Does it output XML or just 'plain text' like in my example?

Comment: I navigated there "directly" as you suggested in your paragraph. I did not run your code.

Comment: @zneak Yeah and I see an XML package there as well. The problem is, when I run my php script, I retrieve that response. But it doesn't seem to be XML. That probably means I'm doing something wrong in my php script but I can't figure out what...

Comment: You asked about this some days ago and I already told you that you need to clean up the code you "just copied over" and clean away all the lines of code that are not necessary. Please comment each line in your example and explain in your own words why you do that and how you test that it works as intended.

Comment: And apart of some warnings, your code is actually working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/w7DVDQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem stays in

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

from php.net: "TRUE to include the header in the output."

as error trace says:

SimpleXMLElement->__construct('HTTP/1.1 200 OK...') #1

and I think it would be better taking out

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
```

as you are already doing an

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

which it the correct way to send POST data

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm afraid I'm still not getting XML data, even when I comment those 2 statements out.

Comment: @Joetjah: It seems there are some understanding problems. Your job is not to comment or uncomment some lines and try over again, it's actually to understand what each line does so you can decide when to use it and when you need to change or remove it. All answers you will get will give you information in that context, nothing more and nothing less. As laxertu correctly answered, this *does work*: http://codepad.viper-7.com/n67NiV